# Magento 2 Breadcrumbs Copy

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

I have the standard breadcrumbs on my page, but I want to add a second copy.

I've tried to add another block the same as defined in module-theme default xml:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="crumbs"/>
```

This does not display.

Should there be a template reference? e.g.

> template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"

How do I add this to my layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can render breadcrumbs in templates(phtml) like below

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

just add the above line in which **phtml** file you want to show breadcrumbs.

It worked for me in category page and product detail page. I tested these two pages only :-)

Comment: how I can add this to block at admin side ?

Comment: i am getting this error on category page can you reply me Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean